# Problems Loading JSAPI from Google

Tags: javascript, jsapi

We're using Google's JSAPI in our webapp (linked, not locally hosted). Most users have no problem. A few, though, seem like the Javascript doesn't load for them. None of the jsapi-dependent functions will fire. When the user clicks the direct link to the API (https://www.google.com/jsapi), she gets a download / save window like this:

[image]

Any thoughts what might be screwing up here? Browser setting? We include jsapi in a script block, not dynamically -- just the basic:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You maybe calling the API from a secure page i.e. HTTPS page.JSAPI is being called on HTTPS but if you look in the browser inspector you will see that it is dynamically calling google input tools page which is a http.Most web browsers don't load such mixed content.